# AUCTeX set LaTeX-default-tabular-environment back to "tabular"

Tags: latex, auctex, elisp-macros

When I use the package `tabularx` in a tex file, if I insert `table` environment, the inner environment will be given as `tabularx` instead of `tabular` when the package `tabularx` is not used.

Normally this would not be a problem for me because I do not deliberately use the package `tabularx`. However, when I use `\documentclasss{memoir}`, the package `tabularx` is automatically used.

I found the variable `LaTeX-default-tabular-environment` and want to reset its value back to `tabular` (now I'm not sure it's the correct variable for me to reset),

```
(eval-after-load 'latex 
    (setq LaTeX-default-tabular-environment "tabular"))
```

but it does not work, and when I query the value for `LaTeX-default-tabular-environment` using `C-h v`, I get the following,

> LaTeX-default-tabular-environment is a variable defined in `latex.el'.
>   Its value is "tabularx"
>
> Local in buffer test-tabularx.tex; global value is "tabular"
>
> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.

Now I am utterly confused. I also tried add some style hook, but it seems to me that I need to alter or update some hook instead just adding it. Could someone help me please? Thanks a lot!

---

After I put the code by Arash Esbati in my `.emacs` file, I noticed the following: even if I do not mention `memoir` in the tex file, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
(cursor here)
\end{document}
```

if I then type <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> `table` <kbd>RET</kbd>(a bunch of them), then I would get `tabular` inside `table` instead of `tabularx` inside `table`. Of course, I later realized that I had another tex file with `\documentclass{memoir}` loaded in emacs. If I kill that buffer and reboot emacs, everything will be as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LaTeX-default-tabular-environment` is the variable you want to reset.  The hook you are looking for is `TeX-update-style-hook`:

> Documentation: Hook run as soon as style specific hooks were applied.

You can use something like this in your init file:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "memoir"
  '(add-hook 'TeX-update-style-hook
             (lambda () (setq LaTeX-default-tabular-environment "tabular"))))
```

---

AUCTeX style files try to follow the same logic as LaTeX packages regarding loading other packages.  AUCTeX has a function `TeX-run-style-hooks` which is comparable to LaTeX's `\RequirePackage` macro.  I presume that you have this in your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

Now when you load a .tex file like this:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
(cursor here)
\end{document}
```

AUCTeX loads the file `memoir.el` which contains the following line:

```lisp
(TeX-run-style-hooks "tabularx")
```

and next it loads the file `tabularx.el` containing:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-default-tabular-environment "tabularx")
```

When you have a .tex file like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
(cursor here)
\end{document}
```

AUCTeX loads the file `tabularx.el` directly.

In general, all these changes should be local to the buffer you're working in, other .tex buffers should not be affected.

Comment: This is great! Just curious, why is this still taking effect even if I do not use the `\documentclass{memoir}`? For example, I just use `\documentclass{memoir}` and `\usepackage{tabularx}` in the preamble.

Comment: @davyjones - You're welcome.  I don't understand your comment, though.  How does your document look like?  Maybe you can add a minimal `.tex` example to your question showing the effect you're describing.

Comment: I added something explanation up in the post. The thing I mentioned above is because I loaded another file of `memoir` class. But this is still weird,  normally emacs+auctex would not recognize packages loaded by another file in another buffer, right?

Comment: I might have an answer to my curiosity. I just found that he function `add-hook` admits a fourth argument, which we can set to `t`. That solves the problem as far as i can test. Many thanks!

Comment: @davyjones - See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again! I changed your solution a little to `(eval-after-load "memoir" '(add-hook 'TeX-update-style-hook (lambda () (setq LaTeX-default-tabular-environment "tabular")) t t))` which makes the hook local (by my understanding).